# Failed try to get alraedy created Surface and recieving EGLNativeWindowType already connected to another API error

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to use Google Cardboard Android SDK which contains native .so files which I suppose contains GL level code in it.

Upon integrating it with another 3D rendering Engine I get following error.

```
> 03-09 21:28:13.322: E/libEGL(29766): EGLNativeWindowType 0x76c99010
> already connected to another API 03-09 21:28:13.322: E/libEGL(29766):
> eglCreateWindowSurface:414 error 3003 (EGL_BAD_ALLOC)
```

Actually during initialization of rendering engine. It is calling,

```
eglCreateWindowSurface(m_display, config, &window, NULL);
```

which is a try to create EGLSurface which I think is already created by Cardboard Native code and thus throwing above mentioned error.

Therefor I am trying to get already created EGLSurface using below command but it is not working either.

```
eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL_DRAW)
```

Here I do not know what exactly to pass in eglGetCurrentSurface EGL_DRAW or EGL_READ. I have tried reading OpenGL documentation but it was not of much help.

Overall I am trying to get EGLContext, EGLSurface and EGLDisplay instead of creating them.

Below is the original code which I am trying to modify.

```
EGLint w, h, dummy, format;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;

    if (!DefaultEGLChooser(m_display, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, config))
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("unable to find a good display type");
        return false;
    }

    eglGetConfigAttrib(m_display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(&window, 0, 0, format);

    static const EGLint contextAttribs[] =
    {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
        2,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(m_display, config, &window, NULL);

    if(m_context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        m_context = eglCreateContext(m_display, config, NULL, contextAttribs);
    }

    if (eglMakeCurrent(m_display, surface, surface, m_context) == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return false;
    }

    //Eegeo_TTY("printing extensions\n");
    //char * extensionsString =  (char *) glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
    //Eegeo_TTY("%s\n",extensionsString);

    Eegeo_GL(eglQuerySurface(m_display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w));
    Eegeo_GL(eglQuerySurface(m_display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h));

    m_surface = surface;

#ifdef EEGEO_DROID_EMULATOR
    m_sharedSurface = EGL_NO_SURFACE;
    m_resourceBuildSharedContext = EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
#else
    if(m_resourceBuildSharedContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        m_resourceBuildSharedContext = eglCreateContext(m_display, config, m_context, contextAttribs);
    }

    EGLint pBufferAttribs[] =
    {
        EGL_WIDTH, 1,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 1,
        EGL_TEXTURE_TARGET, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
        EGL_TEXTURE_FORMAT, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
        EGL_NONE
    };
    EGLConfig sharedSurfaceConfig;
    if (!DefaultEGLChooser(m_display, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT, sharedSurfaceConfig))
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("unabled to find a good pbuffer surface type");
    }

    m_sharedSurface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(m_display, sharedSurfaceConfig, pBufferAttribs);
#endif
```

and below is my modified version which gives me black screen.

```
    EGLint w, h, dummy, format;
    EGLConfig config;
    EGLSurface surface;

    if (!DefaultEGLChooser(m_display, EGL_WINDOW_BIT, config))
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("unable to find a good display type");
        return false;
    }

    eglGetConfigAttrib(m_display, config, EGL_NATIVE_VISUAL_ID, &format);

    ANativeWindow_setBuffersGeometry(&window, 0, 0, format);

    static const EGLint contextAttribs[] =
    {
        EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION,
        2,
        EGL_NONE
    };
//  surface = eglCreateWindowSurface(m_display, config, &window, NULL);
    surface =  eglGetCurrentSurface(EGL_DRAW);


    if(m_context == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        m_context = eglGetCurrentContext();
    }

    if (eglMakeCurrent(m_display, surface, surface, m_context) == EGL_FALSE)
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("Unable to eglMakeCurrent");
        return false;
    }

    Eegeo_GL(eglQuerySurface(m_display, surface, EGL_WIDTH, &w));
    Eegeo_GL(eglQuerySurface(m_display, surface, EGL_HEIGHT, &h));

    Eegeo_TTY("%.2f , %.2f", w, h);

    m_surface = surface;

#ifdef EEGEO_DROID_EMULATOR
    m_sharedSurface = EGL_NO_SURFACE;
    m_resourceBuildSharedContext = EGL_NO_CONTEXT;
#else
    if(m_resourceBuildSharedContext == EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
    {
        m_resourceBuildSharedContext = eglCreateContext(m_display, config, m_context, contextAttribs);
    }

    EGLint pBufferAttribs[] =
    {
        EGL_WIDTH, 1,
        EGL_HEIGHT, 1,
        EGL_TEXTURE_TARGET, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
        EGL_TEXTURE_FORMAT, EGL_NO_TEXTURE,
        EGL_NONE
    };

    EGLConfig sharedSurfaceConfig;
    if (!DefaultEGLChooser(m_display, EGL_PBUFFER_BIT, sharedSurfaceConfig))
    {
        Eegeo_ERROR("unabled to find a good pbuffer surface type");
    }

    m_sharedSurface = eglCreatePbufferSurface(m_display, sharedSurfaceConfig, pBufferAttribs);
#endif
```

Comment: Any solution for this?

Comment: @PerracoLabs I was facing this issue with an SDK whose GL code was inside a library, thus I was unable to fix this. As a result, I implemented basic mesh rendering inside that engine instead of using cardboard sdk.

Comment: i am facing exactly the same problem and seeking for solution T_T